# removing duplicate dates for a given variable in R

Tags: r

```
Date    Server  CPU
1/1/2012    WebA    30
1/1/2012    WebA    25
1/1/2012    WEbB    30
1/2/2012    WebA    45
1/2/2012    WebA    50
1/2/2012    WebA    60

dput(x)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1/1/2012", 
"1/2/2012"), class = "factor"), Server = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("WebA", "WEbB"), class = "factor"), 
    CPU = c(30L, 25L, 30L, 45L, 50L, 60L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Server", "CPU"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

I should have one data point for each data for a given Server. I need to remove duplicate dates. When I pick the Date, CPU should be the highest. For example, for Date 1/2/2012, my new row would be `1/2/2012 WebA 60`.

How do I go about removing the duplicate dates in R?

I can do this:

```
x[!duplicated(x[1:2]),]
```

from the CPU, how do I check the highest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(df$CPU, by=list(df$Date, df$Server), max)

#    Group.1 Group.2  x
# 1 1/1/2012    WebA 30
# 2 1/2/2012    WebA 60
# 3 1/1/2012    WEbB 30
```

Using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
setkey(dt, "Date", "Server")
dt[, list(CPU.max = max(CPU)), by="Date,Server"]

#        Date Server CPU.max
# 1: 1/1/2012   WebA      30
# 2: 1/1/2012   WEbB      30
# 3: 1/2/2012   WebA      60
```

**Edit:** Following OP's comments asking for more columns:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
               .Label = c("1/1/2012", "1/2/2012"), class = "factor"), 
               Server = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
               .Label = c("WebA", "WEbB"), class = "factor"), 
               CPU = c(30L, 25L, 30L, 45L, 50L, 60L), 
               val1 = c(5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 4L), 
               val2 = c(5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L), 
               val3 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L)), 
               .Names = c("Date", "Server", "CPU", "val1", "val2", "val3"), 
               row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

> df

#       Date Server CPU val1 val2 val3
# 1 1/1/2012   WebA  30    5    5    1
# 2 1/1/2012   WebA  25    2    3    2
# 3 1/1/2012   WEbB  30    6    6    4
# 4 1/2/2012   WebA  45    3    4    3
# 5 1/2/2012   WebA  50    1    1    6
# 6 1/2/2012   WebA  60    4    2    5
```

Solution using `aggregate`: Using aggregate with formulae (as shown below) is better in general because 1) it preserves column names, 2) it is clean and easy to understand and 3) it allows for easier merge to recover other columns (due to (1)) (and this is your question, if I got it right).

```
df.agg <- aggregate(data = df, CPU ~ Date + Server, max)
merge(df.agg, df)

#       Date Server CPU val1 val2 val3
# 1 1/1/2012   WebA  30    5    5    1
# 2 1/1/2012   WEbB  30    6    6    4
# 3 1/2/2012   WebA  60    4    2    5
```

Solution using `data.table`:

```
dt <- data.table(df, key=c("Date", "Server"))
# .SD holds the data.frame of the current group that is processed
dt[, .SD[which.max(CPU)], by=c("Date", "Server")]

#        Date Server CPU val1 val2 val3
# 1: 1/1/2012   WebA  30    5    5    1
# 2: 1/1/2012   WEbB  30    6    6    4
# 3: 1/2/2012   WebA  60    4    2    5
```

Comment: what if I have many other columns, but I would like to make sure there are not duplicate dates and Server?

Comment: @user1471980, please check the edit. I hope it clarifies things.

Answer (score 2):

And just for the fun, another one with `plyr` :

```
library(plyr)
ddply(x, c("Date", "Server"), summarize, cpumax=max(CPU))
```

Comment: (+1) I missed the plyr solution!